# Save calculated fields value to another table

Tags: delphi

I have added a new field to my table and made it a calculated field. I would like to save its value to another table. However, my query (that I use for inserting its value)  does not recognize this calculated field as a part of the table and keeps throwing me the error that there's no such field. What am I missing here ?

```
UNIQuery3.SQL.Text :='INSERT or ignore into MAIN (LOK_ID,Date,surname,name,T1,T2,T1_1,T2_2,X1)'
 + 'select LOK_ID,Date,surname,name,T1,T2,T1_1,T2_2,X1 from TEMP';
UNIQuery3.ExecSQL;
```

X1 is calculated in table TEMP. In MAIN is integer.

Comment: Show some code. Calculated field exists only in your code, and is not known to sql operating on tables in the database.

Comment: How do I overcome this ? Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embed the value of `X1` in sql directly:

```
var
  x1: integer;
begin
...
  x1 := table.FieldByname('X1').AsInteger;
...
 + 'select LOK_ID,Date,surname,name,T1,T2,T1_1,T2_2,' + IntToStr(x1) + ' from TEMP';
```

Comment: I have just one small question igor. If I have 2 more fields like this to save, would the syntax be : ' + IntToStr(x1) + ',' + IntToStr(x12) + ',' + IntToStr(x3) + ' from TEMP ???

Comment: why don't you try it? And yes.

Comment: thanks....I had in  mind something else...never mind...I learned something today..:)